# WaveletComp misreading data

Tags: r, time-series, wavelet

Here's the structure of my data:

```
'data.frame':   275 obs. of  2 variables:
$ Date         : Date, format: "1993-07-05" "1993-08-30" "1993-09-27" "1993-10-25" ...
$ AverageOxygen: num  4.11 3.8 3.65 5.77 5.23 ...
```

I'm trying to get WaveletComp to analyze my wavelet using this code:

```
library(WaveletComp)
analyze.wavelet(WaveletSite1Oxygen, loess.span = 1/25,
            dt = 1, dj = 1/250,
            lowerPeriod = 2*dt,
            upperPeriod = floor(nrow(WaveletSite1Oxygen)/3)*dt,
            make.pval = TRUE, method = "white.noise", params = NULL,
            n.sim = 100,
            date.format = NULL, date.tz = NULL,
            verbose = TRUE)
```

For some reason, I'm getting this error which doesn't seem to make sense:

> Error in analyze.wavelet(WaveletSite1Oxygen, loess.span = 1/25, dt = 1,  : 
>     Some values in your time series do not seem to be interpretable as numbers.

I'm not sure how this is happening because all my variables are in the right format and there are no NAs.

Thank you for your help.

Here's the dput of the data

```
WaveletSite1Oxygen <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(8586, 8642, 8670, 8698, 8726, 
8754, 8789, 8817, 8845, 8873, 8915, 8951, 9006, 9034, 9062, 9091, 
9153, 9181, 9209, 9244, 9272, 9304, 9342, 9370, 9399, 9426, 9459, 
9524, 9559, 9587, 9622, 9706, 9734, 9762, 9797, 9825, 9860, 9888, 
9903, 9946, 10010, 10050, 10095, 10133, 10161, 10178, 10224, 
10252, 10280, 10308, 10339, 10417, 10469, 10497, 10525, 10553, 
10567, 10609, 10641, 10665, 10707, 10742, 10767, 10802, 10830, 
10858, 10893, 10907, 10984, 11012, 11040, 11054, 11159, 11187, 
11229, 11257, 11271, 11313, 11341, 11375, 11411, 11435, 11467, 
11495, 11509, 11552, 11580, 11636, 11664, 11734, 11762, 11797, 
11809, 11867, 11895, 11923, 11951, 11979, 12021, 12035, 12077, 
12105, 12133, 12160, 12189, 12231, 12259, 12273, 12315, 12343, 
12385, 12399, 12441, 12469, 12497, 12535, 12553, 12592, 12630, 
12658, 12686, 12714, 12742, 12770, 12805, 12833, 12861, 12903, 
12917, 12938, 12987, 13015, 13056, 13085, 13116, 13138, 13179, 
13201, 13232, 13259, 13287, 13323, 13358, 13386, 13413, 13442, 
13470, 13497, 13532, 13561, 13603, 13630, 13658, 13694, 13722, 
13750, 13778, 13792, 13846, 13862, 13896, 13925, 13967, 13995, 
14009, 14051, 14064, 14121, 14149, 14177, 14205, 14233, 14268, 
14296, 14310, 14352, 14380, 14450, 14474, 14506, 14548, 14575, 
14590, 14618, 14661, 14688, 14726, 14758, 14821, 14849, 14877, 
14905, 14933, 14960, 14995, 15024, 15038, 15093, 15121, 15135, 
15181, 15209, 15237, 15264, 15308, 15322, 15353, 15399, 15427, 
15455, 15483, 15510, 15539, 15580, 15608, 15636, 15666, 15692, 
15729, 15741, 15780, 15811, 15853, 15911, 15940, 15961, 15996, 
16024, 16052, 16101, 16150, 16178, 16218, 16276, 16303, 16331, 
16374, 16401, 16417, 16455, 16482, 16513, 16555, 16585, 16612, 
16638, 16667, 16706, 16723, 16752, 16778, 16805, 16840, 16891, 
16918, 16933, 16976, 17044, 17120, 17143, 17178, 17219, 17233, 
17261, 17289, 17347, 17373, 17401, 17460, 17515, 17547, 17583, 
17602, 17626, 17653), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date", class = "Date"), 
    AverageOxygen = c(4.11230769230769, 3.80128205128205, 3.64576923076923, 
    5.76538461538462, 5.23153846153846, 5.14807692307692, 4.26590909090909, 
    3.71666666666667, 4.35884615384615, 3.25769230769231, 4.85288461538462, 
    5.61923076923077, 4.35576923076923, 5.72884615384615, 7.22692307692308, 
    2, 4.21923076923077, 4.67211538461538, 5.125, 4.74230769230769, 
    4.28846153846154, 5.10384615384615, 6.06346153846154, 3.24230769230769, 
    6.07884615384615, 5.89615384615385, 4.54807692307692, 5.21442307692308, 
    5.48461538461538, 6.70769230769231, 5.36538461538461, 5.17483974358974, 
    5.95, 5.55384615384615, 5.67153846153846, 5.53769230769231, 
    5.78307692307692, 6.57307692307692, 6.49192307692308, 6.36153846153846, 
    6.71992307692308, 6.51936923076923, 6.41, 7.14782608695652, 
    6.11307692307692, 6.20961538461538, 6.85277777777778, 6.82277777777778, 
    6.82846153846154, 6.35384615384615, 5.15769230769231, 6.64, 
    6.39384615384615, 6.88179487179487, 6.44153846153846, 6.82192307692308, 
    7.45923076923077, 7.03730769230769, 7.01214285714286, 6.99326923076923, 
    6.83269230769231, 7.20188461538462, 5.94901602564103, 4.195, 
    5.11826923076923, 6.94230769230769, 6, 9.515, 7.95634615384615, 
    7.645, 6.72096153846154, 6.09538461538462, 6.65636639676113, 
    6.80596153846154, 6.19564102564103, 7.03442307692308, 6.52769230769231, 
    7.48740384615385, 7.22692307692308, 7.05307692307692, 6.06953846153846, 
    5.41384615384615, 7.17278846153846, 7.47373076923077, 7.1822792022792, 
    6.80788461538462, 7.24076923076923, 7.54961538461538, 5.55653846153846, 
    8.41923076923077, 6.75423076923077, 7.13653846153846, 7.00192307692308, 
    7.09538461538462, 7.29730769230769, 7.42903846153846, 5.87115384615385, 
    5.94153846153846, 6.42153846153846, 6.74269230769231, 5.88730769230769, 
    6.41692307692308, 6.82653846153846, 6.34096153846154, 6.19807692307692, 
    6.79384615384615, 6.56230769230769, 4.40576923076923, 6.54115384615385, 
    6.02884615384615, 5.75666666666667, 5.01076923076923, 5.55115384615385, 
    7.14961538461538, 5.77942307692308, 6.22141025641026, 6.66192307692308, 
    6.06788461538462, 5.91153846153846, 5.37692307692308, 5.61346153846154, 
    5.40192307692308, 6.41019230769231, 5.07961538461538, 5.09391025641026, 
    2.42012820512821, 1.75173076923077, 4.14705128205128, 4.44538461538462, 
    4.42269230769231, 2.94395833333333, 4.88153846153846, 5.15941483516484, 
    5.35596153846154, 5.26211538461538, 4.02961538461538, 2.60641254578755, 
    1.14916666666667, 4.67846153846154, 4.47653846153846, 3.97942307692308, 
    2.27812937062937, 1.98057692307692, 1.92730769230769, 4.65846153846154, 
    4.47173076923077, 5.02192307692308, 5.22423076923077, 4.07393162393162, 
    3.72826923076923, 3.01666666666667, 3.96634615384615, 4.85800480769231, 
    6.00442307692308, 6.44865384615385, 6.33692307692308, 5.90365384615385, 
    6.57846153846154, 5.57615384615385, 6.25384615384615, 5.31096153846154, 
    5.13022435897436, 4.98307692307692, 5.95038461538462, 4.89730769230769, 
    5.2225, 5.805, 5.91642081447964, 5.97115384615385, 5.25051282051282, 
    6.03519230769231, 5.66884615384615, 5.87538461538461, 6.06269230769231, 
    5.81807692307692, 5.94423076923077, 6.19153846153846, 5.54194762684124, 
    5.31923076923077, 6.35384615384615, 6.92051282051282, 7.19038461538462, 
    3.90384615384615, 7.64230769230769, 6.03589743589744, 6.51538461538462, 
    6.92820512820513, 6.81153846153846, 6.55897435897436, 6.36192307692308, 
    7.22307692307692, 6.10961538461538, 5.93653846153846, 6.85, 
    6.66538461538462, 5.12307692307692, 6.06153846153846, 6.42179487179487, 
    6.32051282051282, 5.85384615384615, 6.27307692307692, 7.02692307692308, 
    7.025, 6.02307692307692, 6.33173076923077, 6.47692307692308, 
    5.37884615384615, 2.38644688644689, 5.91538461538462, 5.31730769230769, 
    4.83461538461538, 1.25149572649573, 1.75757936507937, 2.47307692307692, 
    4.47115384615385, 4.81548717948718, 4.43502747252747, 5.33873626373626, 
    5.19423076923077, 5.90384615384615, 4.84038461538462, 5.45769230769231, 
    5.89487179487179, 1.63846153846154, 5.35576923076923, 7.03846153846154, 
    5.59230769230769, 5.84230769230769, 6.024, 3.81153846153846, 
    3.83846153846154, 5.7, 6.10769230769231, 5.32307692307692, 
    5.59423076923077, 6.86923076923077, 6.69028286528286, 6.57792022792023, 
    5.83846153846154, 3.90384615384615, 0.761111111111111, 3.08098290598291, 
    4.68205128205128, 4.51730769230769, 5.82692307692308, 1.52692307692308, 
    2.55769230769231, 2.41410256410256, 2.32142697881828, 2.16333333333333, 
    0.778571428571429, 1.40384615384615, 2.93846153846154, 2.74326923076923, 
    5.20769230769231, 3.86269230769231, 4.02076923076923, 2.32545833333333, 
    4.35038461538462, 5.60307692307692, 3.755, 5.00961538461539, 
    4.36307692307692, 3.245, 4.38769230769231, 3.26269230769231, 
    4.00121082621083, 4.79653846153846, 4.46518518518519, 5.34461538461538, 
    0.555384615384615, 2.92332867132867, 4.17307692307692, 4.87461538461538, 
    5.50230769230769)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-275L))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Do you have `dt` defined elsewhere? Or are you trying to use the default values for the function? If the latter, you should not include them when you call the function. Values you pass into a function are handled differently than default parameter values.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, here's the minimum reproducible example:
`data <- data.frame(
        Date = sample(c("1993-07-05", "1993-07-05", "1993-07-05", "1993-08-30", "1993-08-30", "1993-08-30", "1993-08-30", "1993-09-04", "1993-09-04")),
        Oxygen = sample(c("0.9", "0.4", "4.2", "5.6", "7.3", "4.3", "9.5", "5.3", "0.3")))`

dt is not defined anywhere else. dt = 1 is the default but after removing that and the values for "lower period" and "upper period", I get the same result.

Comment: Well, in that sample both Date and Oxygen are character values and not dates or numbers. You can't run this function on character values. Are you sure that matches your real data?

Comment: Woops, this should fix it to be identical to what I'm dealing with:
`data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date)
 data$Oxygen <- as.numeric(data$Oxygen)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accodring to the documentation, the `my.data` parameter should be

> data frame of time series (including header, and dates as row names or as separate column named "date" if available)

You have a column named "Date", not "date" (R is case sensitive). And then the `my.series` parameter says it expects

> name or column index indicating the series to be analyzed

Since the default is 1, that means it will try to take the first column in your data set which is the Date column. But you really want the `AverageOxygen` column.

We can create a new column with the right "date" name and analyze the correct column with

```
analyze.wavelet(transform(WaveletSite1Oxygen, date=Date), my.series="AverageOxygen")
```